# PHP Query inserting data from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have table A(predictions) consisting of columns from table B(fixtures) and table C(user registration table). 
Each time a new user registers I want to add their username to table A along with a data from all data from table B.

When I register a new user it only inserts the users data into table A(predictions) and the first row from table B(predictions).

What i want to achieve is; when a new user registers their username name will be added into the username column along with along the fixtures from the season, therefore the username is inserted in each row for each fixture:

Pred_ID  | Fix_ID | Home_Team | Home_Score  | Away_Score | Away_Team | username

1  -----------1 -------Man U------------------- 7-------------0-----------------Arsenal------B.Rubble

2  -----------1 -------Man U------------------- 5-------------0----------------Arsenal-------B.Rubble

3  -----------2 -------Chelsea------------------0-------------1----------------Leister-------New.user

4  -----------2 -------Chelsea------------------  0------------3----------------Leister--------New.user

Using The insert function

```
public function insert($table, $fields = array()) {

    $keys   = array_keys($fields);
    $values = '';
    $x      = 1;

    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        $values .= '?';
        if ($x < count($fields)) {

            $values .= ', ';
        } //are we at end of defined fields

        $x++;
    }


    $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} (`" . implode('`, `', $keys) . "`) VALUES ({$values})";

    if (!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
        return true;
    }


    return false;
}
```

Im using the following updatePredTable() function

```
public function updatePredTable($fields=array()){
    if(!$this->_db->insert('predict', $fields)) {
        throw new Exception('There was a problem creating an account');
    }
}
```

register.php

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';

include 'navbar.php';

$prediction = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM fixtures");

if (!$prediction->count()) {
    echo 'No preds';
} else {  
    foreach ($prediction->results() as $row) {

        $row = get_object_vars($row);
        echo $row['Home_Team'], '<br>';

        if (Input::exists()) {
            if (Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

                var_dump(Token::check(Input::get('token')));


                //echo 'I have been run'; 
                $validate   = new Validate();
                $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(

                    'username' => array(

                        'required' => true,
                        'min' => 2,
                        'max' => 20,
                        'unique' => 'users'
                    ),
                    'password' => array(

                        'required' => true,
                        'min' => 6


                    ),
                    'password_again' => array(

                        'required' => true,
                        'matches' => 'password'
                    ),
                    'name' => array(

                        'required' => true,
                        'min' => 2,
                        'max' => 50
                    )

                ));

                if ($validation->passed()) {

                    //Session::flash('Success', 'You registered successfully!');
                    //header('Location: index.php');

                    $user = new User();
                    $salt = Hash::salt(32);

                    try {

                        $user->create(array(

                            'username' => Input::get('username'),
                            'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'), $salt),
                            'salt' => $salt,
                            'name' => Input::get('name'),
                            'joined' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                            'group' => 1   
                        ));

                        $user->updatePredTable(array(
                            'username' => Input::get('username'),
                            'fixture_ID' => $row['Fixture_ID'],
                            'date' => $row['Date'],
                            'home_Team' => $row['Home_Team'],
                            'away_Team' => $row['Away_Team']
                        ));

                        Session::flash('home', 'You have been registered you can now log in!');
                        //like:
                        //header('Location: index.php');

                        Redirect::to('index.php');  
                    }
                    catch (Exception $e) {
                        die($e->getMessage());
                    }
                    //echo 'Passed';
                } else {
                    foreach ($validation->errors() as $error) {
                        echo $error, '<br>';
                        //print_r($validation->errors());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }  
}


?>
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what the trouble is. Can you possibly edit your question to include actual output vs. desired?

Comment: i've updated question if you want to have a look

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look at where you loop over the predictions result set. It looks like on the first iteration you are redirecting to index.php hence only one row is added try looping over the resultset as below

```
 <?php
require_once 'core/init.php';

include 'navbar.php';

$prediction = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM fixtures");

if (!$prediction->count()) {
    echo 'No preds';
} else {  


        if (Input::exists()) {
            if (Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

                var_dump(Token::check(Input::get('token')));


                //echo 'I have been run'; 
                $validate   = new Validate();
                $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(

                    'username' => array(

                        'required' => true,
                        'min' => 2,
                        'max' => 20,
                        'unique' => 'users'
                    ),
                    'password' => array(

                        'required' => true,
                        'min' => 6


                    ),
                    'password_again' => array(

                        'required' => true,
                        'matches' => 'password'
                    ),
                    'name' => array(

                        'required' => true,
                        'min' => 2,
                        'max' => 50
                    )

                ));

                if ($validation->passed()) {

                    //Session::flash('Success', 'You registered successfully!');
                    //header('Location: index.php');

                    $user = new User();
                    $salt = Hash::salt(32);

                    try {

                        $user->create(array(

                            'username' => Input::get('username'),
                            'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'), $salt),
                            'salt' => $salt,
                            'name' => Input::get('name'),
                            'joined' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                            'group' => 1   
                        ));

foreach ($prediction->results() as $row) {

        $row = get_object_vars($row);
        echo $row['Home_Team'], '<br>';

                        $user->updatePredTable(array(
                            'username' => Input::get('username'),
                            'fixture_ID' => $row['Fixture_ID'],
                            'date' => $row['Date'],
                            'home_Team' => $row['Home_Team'],
                            'away_Team' => $row['Away_Team']
                        ));
}
                        Session::flash('home', 'You have been registered you can now log in!');
                        //like:
                        //header('Location: index.php');

                        Redirect::to('index.php');  
                    }
                    catch (Exception $e) {
                        die($e->getMessage());
                    }
                    //echo 'Passed';
                } else {
                    foreach ($validation->errors() as $error) {
                        echo $error, '<br>';
                        //print_r($validation->errors());
                    }
                }

        }
    }  
}
```

I haven't tested this but hopefully it will point you in the right direction